# How do i stop the variable from resetting

Tags: c#, .net, taglib-sharp, cscore

In my code I have a method with the two parameters.
One parameter takes in an int value and the other an array.

e.g

```
 public void NextSong(int i, TagLib.File[] queue)
 {
    i++;
    SONG_URL = queue[i].Name;
    Stop();
    Play();
 }
```

My problem here is every time this variable is called like so:

```
NextSong(0, SongQueue);
```

It reverts back to the amount placed in the parameter field.  How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

```
public int NextSong(int i, TagLib.File[] queue)
{
    i++;
    SONG_URL = queue[i].Name;
    Stop();
    Play();
    return i;
}

int i = 0;
i= NextSong(i, SongQueue);
```

Here we are passing a variable of `i` to the method, during the method we increment that variable and then pass it back via the return. We now have reference to that variable.

OR

```
public void NextSong(TagLib.File[] queue, out int i)
{
    i++;
    SONG_URL = queue[i].Name;
    Stop();
    Play();
}

int i = 0;
NextSong(SongQueue, out i);
```

This uses the out functionality, which enforces someone to pass a variable that will be returned. It passes the variable by reference (You could also use ref, but since `int` can't be null, it doesn't change much in this case).

Comment: See here for more details on `out` and also `ref`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Comment: Answer is correct, also include some explanation/ description.

Answer (score 2):

That is working as expected, as long as 0 it will keep on being passed, the variable will always reset.

What you can do it to change the signature of the `NextSong` method to yield back the value of `i`:

```
public int NextSong(int i, TagLib.File[] queue)
{
    i++;
    SONG_URL = queue[i].Name;
    Stop();
    Play();

    return i;
}
```

Then in your code you initialize some global value to `0` and call the method as follows: `globalVariable = NextSong(globalVariable, SongQueue)`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by initialising a  global variable then I incremented the variable and added it the method parameter.

I also removed the increment within the method

Thanks for the help though!